# Setting variable value using merge operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-merge

```
Declare  @IsInserted  Bit
Declare  @Date Datetime=Getdate();

MERGE MASTERSUBJECT AS T
USING #TEMPSUBJECT AS S 
ON T.ID=S.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (TITLE,OREDRNO,DTMADD,[STATUS]) 
VALUES(S.TITLE,(select MAX(OREDRNO)+1 from 
MASTERSUBJECT),@DATE,1) 
SET  @IsInserted=1     /* IF the record is inserted*/
```

In the above code I want to update `@IsInserted` variable to 1 if the insert is successful.

Comment: whats your current error?

Comment: 1. You don't need MERGE here; 2. Use @@ROWCOUNT after INSERT to check it

Comment: Sorry But I want to use merge if you have any way of  doing it then please let me know

Answer (score 1):

For merge, you don't need a variable here. Just use the OUTPUT clause. It is what it was designed for.

```
OUTPUT
   $action,
   inserted.*,
```

Or, an alternative...

```
DECLARE @IsInserted int
SET @IsInserted= ISNULL(@IsInserted, SCOPE_IDENTITY());
```